# How do you change the label text with javascript in a firefox addon?

Tags: firefox-addon

How do you change the label text with javascript in a firefox addon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more context would help, but if `myLabel` is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/label) element (gotten by `document.getElementById` or something) then you can just do `myLabel.value = 'new text'`.

Some other elements have a label as well, often set using the `label` attribute.